# Can Facebook advertising be targetted only to users with an email address?

Tags: email, advertising, facebook, ad-targeting

We are trying to promote our website with Facebook ads.   We are finding a sizable percentage of users that come in through those FB ads are trying to sign up for our site but don't have an email address.   They seemed to have signed up for FB with a phone number.

Our website isn't set up for login without an email address.   We don't have the mechanisms in place to communicate with users through texts.   As such, these users get frustrated that they can't use our site and we wasted money to show ads to them.

Most of these users are coming from India where is it very common to only have a phone and not a computer.  I know we could exclude countries with our advertising, but I'd rather find a finer grain solution if possible.

Can we set our ads to not show to FB users that don't have an email address associated with their account?